# Swift JSON Decoder is NIL but works in web browser - Google Places API

Tags: swift, google-places-api, jsondecoder

Trying to get the results of a Google Places API call. This code worked until a few weeks ago. I get the results which conform to a Places Struct.

The print url line gives me a url that gives me json data, but when I try and print the response after the JSON decoding I get nil.

```
  let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    
    func getGooglePlacesData(forKeyword keyword: String, location: CLLocation, withinMeters radius: Int, using completionHandler: @escaping (GooglePlacesResponse) -> ())  {
         
        let url = googlePlacesDataURL(forKey: googlePlacesKey, location: location, keyword: keyword)
         let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (responseData, _, error) in
                                                
             if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                  return
             }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            
            print(url)
                     
            guard let data = responseData, let response = try? decoder.decode(GooglePlacesResponse.self, from: data) else {
                  completionHandler(GooglePlacesResponse(results:[]))
                  return
             }
             completionHandler(response)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Did something change in how we are supposed to decode JSON data?

Comment: Don't print the url. print the responseData (String) `String(data: responseData!, encoding: .utf8)!` and don't print the `error.localizedDescription` just `print(error)`

Comment: Btw note that in your URLSession dataTask method  if an error occurs the `completionHandler` will never be called. I would suggest to change your method declaration to return optional GooglePlacesResponse and optional error.

Comment: Rather than ignoring a DecodingError with `try?` add a `do - catch` block and `print` the error.